# Symbol for cover

Tags: notation

Is there a symbol for the cover operator? Given two family of sets(lets say $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$)

$$ \mathcal{A} = \{A_1, A_2, ..., A_m\}$$
$$ \mathcal{B} = \{B_1, B_2, ..., B_n\}$$

$\mathcal{A}$ covers $\mathcal{B}$ iff the following condition is satisfied

$$\forall_{B_i \in \mathcal{B}} \; \exists_{A_j \in \mathcal{A}} \; B_i \subseteq A_j$$

I was wondering if there was a symbol for the operator that depicts this cover - $\mathcal{A} \; <op> \; \mathcal{B}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After receiving a few suggestions, I decided to go with $\triangleleft$ (`\triangleleft`)

Therefore $\mathcal{A}$ covers $\mathcal{B}$ is denoted by the following equation

$$\mathcal{A} \triangleleft \mathcal{B}$$

Some other suggestions I received include

- $\mathcal{G}$ (`\mathcal{G}`)
- $\mathcal{C}$ (`\mathcal{C}`)